# Is there a way to use software which requires a graphic card through windows 10 remote control?

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, remote-desktop, remote-access

I recently started using windows 10 remote control to use my home pc trough a weak laptop (for when I can't bring my PC but my laptop isn't fast/strong enough).

It works pretty well, but during a pause, I wanted to play some games and got some errors about DirectX and D3D.
I searched for these errors and, from what I understood, found out that it is due to remote control not allowing the PC to use the graphic card of my home PC.

I then tried to figure out how I could make the PC use the graphic card correctly but didn't found anything useful.

**Is there a way to use my distant computer's graphic card while using windows 10 remote control?**

(I initially asked this question [here on networking engineering](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/63601/63360) where it didn't fit the scope of questions so they suggested that I may post it here on Super User SE.)

Comment: Is this related to what you're trying to do? https://superuser.com/questions/1276562/is-it-possible-to-offload-graphics-processing-onto-another-computer-on-the-netwo

Comment: @MC10 I was just about to suggest using Nvidia Shield or Steam Game Streaming rather than RDP... forgot I wrote that answer. They are pretty much the best solution to the problem. RDP was made for a different type of remote machine work to the Gaming orientated stuff. It boils down to accuracy vs speed/latency.

Comment: @MC10 Thank you for the suggestion, I'll take a look it when I come back home.

Comment: Where are the games run? Laptop or PC?

Comment: @harrymc games are run on my PC.

Answer (score 0):

After some time trying to figure it out, I found [this tutorial](https://knowledge.civilgeo.com/knowledge-base/enabling-gpu-rendering-for-microsoft-remote-desktop/) on how to activate GPU rendering while using Windows 10 Remote Control.

Here's a quick walkthrough of the process for posterity:

On the PC you want to connect to, open *Windows Run Dialog* (Win + R) and open **gpedit.msc** to access the *Local Group Policy Editor*.

Then navigate through the folders following this path :
*Administrative Templates* > *Windows Components* > *Remote Desktop Services* > *Remote Desktop Session Host* > *Remote Session Environment* > *RemoteFX for Windows Server*

You'll then have three items in this folder:

- Configure RemoteFX
- Optimize visual experience when using RemoteFX
- Optimize visual experience for Remote Desktop Service Sessions

For each of these items, you'll have to right-click, **Edit**, check **Enabled** in the opened config window then click **Ok** to apply it.

---

**This part only applies to old window 10 versions, as these elements have been removed now.**

> Then you have to select in the folder tree *Remote Session
> Environment*, the parent folder of the folder you're currently in.
>
> There will be a lot more items in this folder, but only two interests
> us :
>
> - Use the hardware default graphics adapter for all Remote Desktop Services sessions
> - Configure compression for RemoteFX data
>
> For these two you'll have to enable them as you did before.

---

Once these Group Policies have been edited, restart the PC to apply changes, and next time you connect to it through Windows 10 remote control you should be able to use heavy graphics rendering applications with your GPU.